# Email Validation in iOS - Regex not working - code contains Array of valid email addresses

Tags: ios, regex

I have an array of supposedly valid emails, Im testing my regex statement to check if my regex method works. Based on this list, they should all return through, however some dont, how would I bullet proof my code so it works accordingly:

```
+(BOOL)isValidEmail: (NSString *)emailString{
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailString];

}
```

The array of valid emails is:

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"johndoe@gmail.com",

                  @"email@example.com",
                  @"firstname.lastname@example.com",
                  @"email@subdomain.example.com",
                  @"firstname+lastname@example.com",
                  @"email@123.123.123.123",
                  @"email@[123.123.123.123]",
                  @"“email”@example.com",
                  @"1234567890@example.com",
                  @"email@example-one.com",
                  @"_______@example.com",
                  @"email@example.name",
                  @"email@example.museum",
                  @"email@example.co.jp",
                  @"firstname-lastname@example.com",
                  nil];
```

I then perform this loop:

```
for (NSString * email in array) {
    NSLog(@"Email: %@ is valid %@",email,[NSString isValidEmail:email] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    ;
}
```

Which logs:

```
 Email: johndoe@gmail.com is valid YES
 Email: email@example.com is valid YES
 Email: firstname.lastname@example.com is valid YES
 Email: email@subdomain.example.com is valid YES
 Email: firstname+lastname@example.com is valid YES
 Email: email@123.123.123.123 is valid NO
 Email: email@[123.123.123.123] is valid NO
 Email: /“email/”@example.com is valid NO
 Email: 1234567890@example.com is valid YES
 Email: email@example-one.com is valid YES
 Email: _______@example.com is valid YES
 Email: email@example.name is valid YES
 Email: email@example.museum is valid NO
 Email: email@example.co.jp is valid YES
 Email: firstname-lastname@example.com is valid YES
```

They should all be valid according to this [Valid email addresses](http://codefool.tumblr.com/post/15288874550/list-of-valid-and-invalid-email-addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[\da-zA-Z_+\\.\-\/(“|”)]+@(([a-zA-Z\-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]+){1,2})|(\[?[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\]?))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, do you know how to make this an NSString?

Comment: Never used NSString but would the same format you have work? NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[\da-zA-Z_+\.\-\/(“|”)]+@(([a-zA-Z\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+){1,2})|(\[?\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\]?))";

Comment: Unfortunately I get an unknown escape sequence '\.'

Comment: try \\. like you have for periods, [\da-zA-Z_+\\.\-\/(“|”)]+@(([a-zA-Z\-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]+){1,2})|(\[?\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\\.\d{1,3}\]?))

Comment: I had to use @"[\\da-zA-Z_+\\.\\-\\/(“|”)]+@(([a-zA-Z\\-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]+){1,2})|([?\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.‌​\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}]?))" . This seems to have fixed .museum returning as not valid, now returns as valid. Could you explain why please? email@123.123.123.123  still returns false, although a valid email address, ive never actually seen one, and dont expect to.

Comment: for the .museum, you had ([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}, the {2,4} limits what is after the . to characters between 2 and 4 in length, I used + (1 or more). the number address I can't say I know why its not returning false, you could try switching [0-9] with \d and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, please update your answer and Ill mark it as correct.